# How to get address of a struct inside its method?

Tags: c#, pointers, struct, garbage-collection

I am able to get the address of a struct outside its (instance) method, as shown below:

```
public struct Values
{
    public byte A;
    public byte B;
    public byte C;
    public byte D;

    public static unsafe bool Equals(Values lhs, Values rhs)
    {
        return *(int*) &lhs == *(int*) &rhs;
    }
}
```

But when I try to get the address of the struct itself, the IDE tells me it's wrong:

```
    public unsafe bool Equals(Values other)
    {
        return *(int*) &this == *(int*) &other;
    }
```

The error message is:

> You can only take the address of an unfixed expression inside of a fixed statement initializer.

The fixed statement prevents the garbage collector from relocating a movable variable.
But this struct is not a movable variable, and will not be garbage collected, right?

**Updated**

What I actually need is to get/set the value of the Nth bytes by index. Although I can do it through switch statement, but it will be faster through index.
Thanks to @KonradKokosa, [Fixed Size Buffer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/unsafe-code-pointers/fixed-size-buffers) meets my needs.
I still want to know the answer to the main question.

Comment: @MichaelRandall I just want to have a instance method which use the pointer of the struct to access the Nth bytes, like ```pSelf[i] = 0;```

Comment: `fixed (Values* p = &this) { return *(ulong*) p == *(ulong*) &other; }` will stop the compiler error however its not going to fix the larger problems here

Comment: @MichaelRandall Yes, you're right. I need to wait for a better solution.

Comment: So you just want to compare the byte (given an offset) of 2 structs? to see if they are equal ?

Comment: @MichaelRandall What I actually need is to get/set the value of the Nth bytes by index. Although I can do it through switch statement, but it will be faster through index.

Comment: Have you cosider using fixed size buffer? `public unsafe struct Values { public fixed byte buf[4]; ...}`. Then you can efficiently get/set bytes byref: `public ref byte this[int index] => ref buf[index];`

Comment: @KonradKokosa It's a good idea, thank you! At the same time, I still want to know the answer to the main question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot take an address of `this` inside struct instance method because **"this struct is not a movable variable"** is not a true statement. Struct may be boxed, and thus immediately it becomes movable. Instance method does not know if it is called from boxed or not-boxed struct.

Note, it is currently a standing limitation also for `ref struct`s, although it could be lifted. So, below code still produces the same compilation error:

```cs
public ref struct C {
    public void M() {
        var ptr = &this;
    }
}
```

However, you can take addresses of structs in a first snippet:

```cs
public static unsafe bool Equals(Values lhs, Values rhs)
{
    return *(int*) &lhs == *(int*) &rhs;
}
```

because you are taking here addresses of local arguments, passed by value (copies of `Values`, in the end).

Comment: Very reasonable explanation.